# Java - request using socket gives 403 response

Tags: java, sockets

The code below gives 403 error. but my request works for localhost:8080 but doesn't for the url mentioned in the code. the url and the folder in the header is completely correct, but i don't understand where the problem lies

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("parsa1234","UTF-8");
            Socket s = new Socket("ramsari.com",80);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            writer.write("POST /help/index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n");
            writer.write("content-length:"+data.length()+"\r\n");
            writer.write("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            writer.write("\r\n");
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            String c = "";
            while((c = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code on ramsari.com/help/index.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
```

and here is the response from the url

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.12.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 15:08:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The 403 Forbidden status means that you have not provided some credential that the server expects. That is, the server you are attempting to access expects you to identify yourself, provide some proof of your identity, and to then have rights to the resource identified by the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP system you are connecting to expects you to prove you are a valid user of that site.

Since your code does not perform the appropriate authentication, and the HTTP server is configured to only respond with the resource you are asking for, the web server has decided to respond with "403 Forbidden" which is a common response code that is sent when an unauthenticated user attempts to access a resource that requires authentication.

Now, there is a high chance that you're also not working with the same web server you think you are using, because you mentioned that the response works at one port, but not at another.  Changing ports can impact the need to authenticate, or even the web "service" handling the request (which again means a possibly different authentication requirement).

I'd look into the web server configuration, and perhaps turn up debugging in the output, and possibly rewrite your client to perform the (if) needed authentication.